# Large data backup service for cPanel servers?

Tags: backup

What is the most affordable service that one can use to store secure backups of cPanel accounts? Backups will run every night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without specifying what companies and products are most affordable -- as such would be a shopping question which is not allowed per FAQs, I will answer canonically on what forms of backup are most affordable.

If you have a large data set (i.e. roughly greater than 500GB as of today), buying extra dedicated servers to host your backup is the most cost efficient in general.

If you have a small data set (i.e. roughly less than 100GB as of today), there are backup services specifically designed for cpanel or custom backup solutions such as via methods like rsync. This method will often be affordable and easiest to setup.

If you're in mid range between the two, well, it's really up to your personal preference.